# How to get this using css?

Tags: html, css, drawing

How can I draw this using css ? I tried using border css and rotate the DIV, but didn't find out exact answer for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use clippath

here is the example link 
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPRjWr)

**html:**

```
<div class="tag-blue" style="-webkit-clip-path: url(#clip1);clip-path: url(#clip1);">gadgets 3</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, .82 1, 0 1">
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**css:**

```
.tag-blue{
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

change path according to your need

Answer (score 1):

You could use pseudo elements, :before : after for this, and transform property:

```
transform-origin: right bottom;
transform: skewY(-3deg);
```

transform-origin - set position of transform animation.
and transform itself set which type and value of animation you want to have

Here is code for your example: https://jsfiddle.net/2zbqgzcq/

And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) you could read more about transform

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using transform property in css, try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.header{
  background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;    
    width: 100%;
}
.header:after{
    content: '';
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: skewY(-4deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
  bottom: -25%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```